# Sinatra + Rack::Session::Pool + Moneta

Tags: session, sinatra, rack

I'm using server side session handling with Moneta in my Sinatra application.

The part of my config.ru looks like that:

```
require 'rack/session/moneta'

use Rack::Session::Moneta do
  use :Expires
  adapter :Memory
end
```

How long does is take for sessions to expire? I couldn't find documentation for it.
I currently delete sessions with

```
get '/logout'
    session.destroy
end
```

But I believe that only destroys the session cookie on the client side.
How can I find the sessions which are currently active?

There is a variable called @pool in Rack::Session. How can I access it from my Sinatra app?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would set the expiration time when storing/accessing session keys by adding the `expires: n` option (set n to 0/false to have disable expiration). Here is [the relevant entry](http://rubydoc.info/github/minad/moneta/master/file/README.md#Expiration) in the Moneta README.